# MySQL display total count of values under limit

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm pretty new to SQL and am currently trying to run a query which will return the total count of a value under a certain limit *(using phpmyadmin)*.

Say we've got a table like so:

```
CarID |  Car | OwnerID
-------------------
1     | Name |   1
2     | Name |   3
3     | Name |   2
4     | Name |   1
```

Now I would like to be able to get the total count of cars a owner has if it's under let's say 2 - to then get this:

```
OwnerID|  TotalCars |
---------------------
2      |      1     | 
3      |      1     |
```

How would I accomplish this? My situation is slightly different than the example I gave but it's fundamentally the same exact goal but just different numbers and more records.

When I try, those with more than the number I wish to see return with zero as their value??

(My code)
[Code giving me trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUCSD.png)

(My result)
[ID 6 has 3 properties so it shouldn't be showing me it at all and I don't understand why it's returning it as 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TC5u.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` `COUNT` and `HAVING`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`CarID` int, `Car` varchar(4), `OwnerID` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`CarID`, `Car`, `OwnerID`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Name', 1),
>     (2, 'Name', 3),
>     (3, 'Name', 2),
>     (4, 'Name', 1)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `OwnerID`, COUNT(*) as countr
> FROM Table1
> GROUP BY `OwnerID`
> HAVING countr < 2
> ```
>
> ```
> OwnerID | countr
> ------: | -----:
>       3 |      1
>       2 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30bc0e387b49b42ef29237d6740edc90)*

Comment: I've accepted it, I tried to upvote but I currently don't have enough reputation, haha.